# QProgressDialog "closes" when another process is started

Tags: c++, qt, process, modal-dialog

In my project, I have a function running while a QProgressDialog shows the progress.

```
QProgressDialog progress("Saving savegame.dat...", "Abort Save", 0, 3016, this);
        progress.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);

//... some loops and other calculations run while I update the progress bar with:
progress.setValue(1000);
```

All is well until I start another process. (Open a cli program)

```
QProcess decomBR;
QStringList filePathListBR;
filePathListBR.append("-o");
filePathListBR.append("stuff\\compress.bms");
filePathListBR.append("stuff\\regions\\xbox_chunks\\br");
filePathListBR.append("stuff\\regions\\xbox_chunks\\br");
decomBR.start("stuff\\quickbms.exe", filePathListBR);
decomBR.waitForFinished();
```

As soon as a process like this is started, the progress bar dialog hides or something and the progress is no longer shown, but the processes still run fine.

Any way to prevent these processes from "closing" the QProgressDialog?

EDIT: So apparently, the dialog isn't closing, it's just the main window is taking priority and "covers" the dialog... if that makes sense. Is there any way to make the dialog maintain display priority?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this, but `setWindowFlags(Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);` may help. Notice that it's a flag, so you'd want to write something like:

```
progress.setWindowsFlags( progress.getWindowsFlags() | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint );
```

Consider using an assertion to see if it's already set, if so then you can dismiss my answer definitively and add to human knowledge by negation!